# Changing record value into its id from antoher table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have got a table A and B. Table A has got:

```
Id | artist | artist_id(that is empty now)
--------------------------------------------
1  | John   |
2  | Jack   |
```

Table B has:

```
artist_id | artist
-------------------
34        | John
56        | Jack
57        | Mike
```

I would like to set artist_id in table A where artist is the same as in B. 
So result would be:

```
Id | artist | artist_id
--------------------------------------------
1  | John   | 34
2  | Jack   | 56
```

How to do it in postgresql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching from names to ids is a good idea.  Assuming that you have no duplicates, this is easily done using a `from` clause or correlated subquery:

```
update a
    set artist_id = b.artist_id
    from b
    where a.name = b.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

this should answer, using `UPDATE` yourtable A and `FROM` the table to JOIN (B)

```
UPDATE TABLEA AS A 
SET A.artist_id = B.artist_id
FROM TABLEB as B
WHERE A.artist = B.artist
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query would work assuming that you have 1 row per each `artist_id` in `tableB` (unique values).

```
UPDATE tableA
SET artist_id = tableB.artist_id
FROM tableB
WHERE tableA.artist = tableB.artist AND tableA.artist_id IS NULL
```